# proof by contrapositive method

Tags: proof-writing

$∀ ∈ ℕ, m^2 + 3$ is even ⟶ $m$ is odd
$P = m^2 + 3$ is even
$Q = m$ is odd

By contrapositive: $¬Q ⟶ ¬P$

1. $¬Q m$ is even,
   $m = 2k$
2. $¬P m^2 + 3$ is odd
   $= (2k)^2 + 3$

Help what I should do now after this step!

Comment: Do you realize that $(2k)^2+3$ is odd for every $k$?

Comment: No , how that !

Comment: $(2k)^2+3=4k^2+3=2(2k^2+1)+1$

Comment: Can you explain how convert the number 3 to 1 because i think it gives a fractional number?

Comment: $4k^2+3=(4k^2+2)+1=2(2k^2+1)+1$. I run out of ways to explain further. The sum of an odd and an even integer is always odd.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, a number is odd if and only if it is of the form $2a+1$ for some integer $a$.

$(2k)^2 + 3 = 4k^2 + 3 = 4k^2 + (2 + 1) = (4k^2 + 2) + 1 = 2(2k^2 + 1) + 1$.

Since $k$ is an integer, $k^2$ is an integer, so $2k^2+1$ is an integer. Let $a=2k^2+1$. Then $m=2a+1$, an odd integer.